# How to modify above-garage storage rack to be adjustable height

Tags: garage

I just installed some garage overhead storage. Link to the exact one [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0194R5BSA) and pictured below. Dimensions are 4' x 8'. The vertical supports are made of two pieces which connect with 2x ~1/4" bolts; this makes it adjustable by deciding how much to overlap those two pieces.

This is a pretty cumbersome process so I would like to modify those vertical supports to have continuous adjustment -- at least 6" or so.

The bottom half of the vertical supports are specialized to give additional support to the platform, but the top half is a pretty basic right angle bracket. I should be able to either modify or replace that top half. But I don't know what to modify it with.

What would be a reasonable way to add continuous vertical adjustment with a mechanism that is also safely load bearing? (The entire rack is rated for 600lb, so let's say the mechanism should be able to safely handle 150lb on a long-term basis). I also don't want to give up the rigidity of the supports since it keeps the platform from swinging around. Right now, all that rigidity comes from the tightness of the bolt at the top, so as long as it's not something like a pully it should be fine.

About me: I am skilled enough to install this roof rack, but that's near the limit of my capabilities. I do have an angle grinder and and most other tools that aren't super specialized.

Hopefully y'all have some good ideas :)

[image: Roof Rack]

Comment: Most adjustable storage racks are really made so you can adjust the height when putting them together and then forget.  They are not made to to go up and down all the time.

Comment: ‘Continuous vertical adjustment’ makes it sound like you want to change the height all the time. How often, really, do you expect to do this?

Comment: I’ve installed product by onrax.com — pricey but decent

Comment: I wouldnt make extra holes in it. It is designed and tested as its shipped. You will make it weak. These types of fixtures also derive some of their strength from everything bring tight. If you want an adjustable one then find one that is designed for it.